# Formatting double to 2 digits after decimal point in J#

Tags: j#

How do you format a `double` value in `J#` to exactly two digits after the decimal point (without doing arithmetic operations)?

```
double x = 3.333333; 
String s = String.Format("\rWork done: {0}%", new Double(x));
System.out.print(s);
```

I thought `J#` was nearly identical to `Java`, but the following `Java` code gives a different result for `J#`:

```
double x = 3.333333; 
String s = String.format("\rWork done %1$.2f%%", x);
System.out.print(s);
```

(Since `J#` is nearly dead and unsupported, I use `Visual J# 2005`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String.format()` API was introduced in Java **1.5**, so there's no chance you can use it in *Visual J++* or *Visual J#*.

There're 2 approaches to your problem.

1. Using the Java **1.1** API (works with any *Java*, *J++* and *J#*):

   ```java
   import java.text.MessageFormat;

   /* ... */

   final double d = 3.333333d;
   System.out.println(MessageFormat.format("{0,number,#.##}", new Object[] {new Double(d)}));
   System.out.println(MessageFormat.format("{0,number,0.00}", new Object[] {new Double(d)}));
   ```

   Note that despite both formats will work for a given double, there's a difference between `0.00` and `#.##`.
2. Using the *.NET* API. Here's the *C#* code fragment that does what you need:

   ```cs
   using System;

   /* ... */

   const double d = 3.333333d;
   Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:F2}", d));
   Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:0.00}", d));
   Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:0.##}", d));
   ```

   Now, the same code translated into *J#*:

   ```java
   import System.Console;

   /* ... */

   final double d = 3.333333d;
   Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Work done {0:F2}%", (System.Double) d));
   Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:Work done 0.00}%", (System.Double) d));
   Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:Work done #.##}%", (System.Double) d));
   ```

   Note that you need to cast the `double` argument to `System.Double`, **not** `java.lang.Double`, in order for formatting to work (see http://www.functionx.com/jsharp/Lesson04.htm).